# Insert white space at the end of each line in file in C#

Tags: c#, whitespace

I have created a text file from an OCR application. Each line ends without any space. But, as the text is read into the textbox in Windows form. The word from the preceding line and the new line gets connected. 
I want to avoid this by having a small c# code that will insert a single white space at the end of each line in the file.
Help is needed for this effect.

The code is doing multiple functions on button click. However, I am sharing a relevant portion of it.

```
    ft = q + ".txt";                // q is the string of path.
   tb5.AppendText(r + t + Environment.NewLine);
   tb5.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(ft) + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    File.Delete(ft);
    File.Delete(k);
```

the file `ft` has the text and it needs adding of space before it gets read into the textbox. After that this file is deleted.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 3):

Change `File.ReadAllText(ft)` to:

```
string.Join(" " + Environment.NewLine, File.ReadAllLines(ft))
```

`File.ReadAllLines()` reads the file into an array of lines, which can be joined into a single string, separated by a space followed by newline.

There are more efficient ways, but this is probably the most simple to code.

For reference:
[`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__)
[`File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_)